# How to rebase a branch in git one revision closer to head of other branch?

Tags: git, rebase

I'm currently working on bringing 2 long diverged branches `feature/A` and `feature/B` of one project back together. They accumulated many confilicting changes in the meantime. Rebasing one on top of the other is infeasible because so much has changed.

Therefore I'm iteratively rebasing `feature/B` one commit closer to the head of `feature/A`.  I'm using a branch called `feature/rebase-target` that tracks the commit on `feature/A` where I'm currently rebasing `feature/B` on. My workflow basically is:

1. `git checkout feature/rebase-target && git rebase <sha-1 of the next commit towards feature/A head>`
2. `git checkout feature/B && git rebase feature/rebase-target`
3. fix conflicts and continue rebase until done
4. manually find the next sha-1 by looking into the log of `feature/A`

How can I automate the search for the sha-1 that is one commit closer to the head of `feature/A` based on the current position of `feature/rebase-target`?

Comment: Consider [git-imerge](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
next_target=$(git rev-list feature/rebase-target..feature/A | tail -n1) &&
git branch -f feature/rebase-target "$next_target"
```

This assumes that the history is linear. If you have merges in the branch leading up to `feature/A`, add `--first-parent`.

Note that `rev-list --reverse -1` does not work, because that would first restrict the normal list to one commit, and *then* reverse the output (which makes no difference if only one is listed).

Note further that in your step 1 you do not have to `checkout` followed by `rebase` (which is a fast-forward if I understand the situation correctly); you can just use `git branch -f` instead.